# Clone database records using ZF1

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to write a function to clone a dataset - that is, to create an identical copy to an existing data set, with different primary keys.

I could do this by reading the records, copying the fields one at a time (or using toArray() and fromArray() and unsetting the primary key and resetting any foreign keys along the way), but I was wondering if there's a built-in method for doing this.

I'm using Zend Framework 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing similar is implemented out of the box in ZF1. You should create [custom Rowset class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.extending.row-rowset) and define custom clone method which can directly access data of Rowset and apply some transformation e.g. filtering or removal etc.